# How to get values of dynamically created input text fields?

Tags: php, html, forms

Sorry for grammar mistakes. I have multiple dynamically created text fields (more than 100). how can i get the values of these fields. i don't know the number of fields. Please help me.

### Example

```
<input type="text" name="id_1" />
<input type="text" name="id_2" />
<input type="text" name="id_3" />

................

<input type="text" name="id_100" />
```

Comment: Can you rename the text inputs?

Comment: Do you want to get them in PHP or javascript?

Comment: @Dharman i want to get in php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arrays:

```
<input type="text" name="id[1]" />
<input type="text" name="id[2]" />
<input type="text" name="id[3]" />
```

Then:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "text $key = $value";
}
```

Comment: I have try your code but it has some syntax error $_POST['id'] as $key $value

Comment: Now I want to implement in insert query

Comment: OK, post another question.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. what if I'm having two arrays of fields (id[], names[]) and I want to loop through one item of the two array per time instead of looping through the complete cycle of id[] before looping through names[]

Answer (score 4):

If you mean you want to get their values in PHP easily, just name them like "name[]".

```
<form method="post" action="yourscript.php">
  <input type="text" name="input[]" />
  <input type="text" name="input[]" />
  <input type="text" name="input[]" />
  <input type="text" name="input[]" />
  <input type="text" name="input[]" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This way you'll be able to get the values in `yourscript.php`. They'll be in `$_POST['input']`. Just loop over it using foreach to get the values:

```
foreach($_POST['input'] as $value) {
  // do what you want with the $value
}
```

Having index numbers in the names like this:

```
<input type="text" name="input[1]" />
<input type="text" name="input[2]" />
```

is redundant.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. what if I'm having two arrays of fields (id[], names[]) and I want to loop through one item of the two array per time instead of looping through the complete cycle of id[] before looping through names[]

Answer (score 2):

In HTML forms, using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("input[name^='id']").each(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('name');  
  var inputValue = this.value;
  console.log(name + " : "+ this.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoa about adding a hidden field to pass the number of fields to the processing script?

```
<input type='hidden' name='num_text_fields' valus='100>
```

The do a for loop to get the values

```
$num_text_fields = $_POST['num_text_fields'];

for ($i=1;$i<=$num_text_fields;$i++) 
    {
    $text_field_name = "id_" . $i;

    $value = $_POST[$text_field_name];

    // do something with $valus
    }
```

Comment: please write complete answer.

Comment: No because you can't be sure all the fields are numbered in order, that's an assumptions. There are arrays for that in PHP

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way to do it is to add a class element to your input.

Then you can be easily able to find them regardless of how many you have